# Cut protocol, host and port from window.location.href

Tags: javascript, window.location

Is there a way to cut protocol, host and port from window.location.href?

Right now I have only this option.

```js
const windowUrlPattern = () => {
  let windowUrl;
  if (window.location.search.length !== 0 && window.location.hash.length === 0) {
    windowUrl = `${window.location.pathname}/${window.location.search}`;
  } else if (window.location.search.length !== 0 && window.location.hash.length !== 0) {
    windowUrl = `${window.location.pathname}/${window.location.search}${window.location.hash}`;
  } else {
    windowUrl = window.location.pathname;
  }
  return windowUrl;
}

console.log(windowUrlPattern());
```

is there a way to make it cleaner or more certain, just to cut window.location.protocol, window.location.host and window.location.port out of href?

thank you.

Comment: Is the extra `/` you have after the `pathname` in the first two cases relevant for your usecase, or is it a typo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean

```js
const windowUrlPattern = href => {
  const url = new URL(href);
  return [url.pathname,url.search,url.hash].join("")
}

console.log(windowUrlPattern(location.href));
console.log(windowUrlPattern("https://www.example.com/folder/page.html"));
console.log(windowUrlPattern("https://www.google.com/search?q=test"));
console.log(windowUrlPattern("https://www.google.com/search?q=test#page2"));
```

Comment: This removes the search and hash parts of the URL...

Comment: Depending on whether the extraneous `/` the OP has is needed or not, could just simply be `${window.location.pathname}${window.location.search}${window.location.hash}` to match the approach he was taking. No need to filter out things that are already blank.

Comment: You can definitely remove the filter part too! empty string is not gonna hurt ;)

Comment: It shouldn't be undefined - the [spec defines both `.search` and `.hash`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/nav-history-apis.html#dom-location-search) to return empty strings if there's nothing there.